# How can I get the CMS page id of a particular page in Magento

Tags: magento

In magento by using this code:

```
$currentPageId =$this->getRequest()->getParam('page_id');
```

we can get the current page id.

But how can I get the page id of a particular page?

For example, I have a page with URL key `about-fruit-store`.

I want to get its page id. How can I get it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either

```
$model = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('about-fruit-store','identifier');
var_dump($model->getData());
var_dump($model->getPageId());
```

or

```
$model = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
->addFieldTofilter('identifier','about-fruit-store')
->getFirstItem();
var_dump($model->getData());
var_dump($model->getPageId());
```

should do it.